# Does NUnit support the concept of an Assembly Teardown?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resource-cleanup

Does NUnit support the concept of an Assembly Teardown similar to the [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssemblyCleanupAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblycleanupattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can be applied to a static method?

This would be run after all the tests within the assembly have completed.  I am currently using NUnit 2.6.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out this functionality does exist in NUnit it is just not very obvious or intuitive.

According to Charlie Poole in the feature request I made for this functionality [here](http://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/1098766), he states the following will work, which is a direct quote from him.

> Decorate a class outside of any namespace with [SetUpFixture].
>   Decorate a method of that class with [TearDown]. If you like, decorate
>   another with [SetUp].
>
> Differences from what you are asking for:
>
> 1. The name makes it a little unobvious in this usage.
> 2. NUnit allows any number of these and calls them all, without any guarantee of ordering. This is by design.
> 3. It can be applied to a static or instance method. If it's an instance method, the class must have a default constructor and it will
>      be created with a lifespan of the entire test run. This is also by
>      design.

Now this is not pretty but it should achieve the same functionality, and maybe he will make it a little cleaner in 3.0. :)

Comment: As of NUnit 3, this throws an exception: `OneTimeSetUp: TearDownAttribute attribute not allowed in a SetUpFixture`, changing it to `[OneTimeTearDown]` fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept in NUnit. But you can apply `TestFixtureTearDownAttribute` to method to free resources obtained by TestFixture.

Comment: Thanks that is what I feared, as there are unmanaged resources used by all TestFixtures that need to be cleaned up and when I ported a MSTest project to NUnit I hit this issue.

Comment: Created a feature request for this to be add to NUNit. If you are interested it can be found here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/nunitv2/+bug/1098766